# totaljs --translate command does not find all texts for translation , despite wrapped in ‘@()’ tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, total.js

I followed [this documentation](https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#pages~Localization)
and executed `total.js --translate` command in the root directory of total.js eshop app. But many words despite wrapped in ‘@()’ tag  not available for translation in the created file.

For example  “@(Category),@(Manufacturer),@(Availability),@(In stock), and more” in product template (`/themes/default/views/cms/product.html`) don’t exist in created “translate.resource” file.

What is the problem here or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Total.js are you using? Try to install latest beta version of Total.js framework as a global module: `$ npm install -g total.js@beta` and try again `--translate`. If your problem still persists, write me an email at info@totaljs.com

Comment: problem still persists. i mailed you. thanks your help.

Comment: how should i translate navigations and They children's name. for example the result of this call `@{foreach m in F.global.navigations.mainmenu.children}
<a href="@{m.url}”>@{m.name}</a>@{end}`

Comment: also what is the way of translating only visitor side of totaljs cms or eshop app. and disable translation of admin side. when i use `@{notranslate};` tag in top of `themes/admin/views/index.html` to disable translating of index.html it can not load at all.